# How to control on div class blocks using the keyboard

Tags: jquery

I'm working on the div class of blocks to control them using the keyboard up and down arrow buttons. I have the list of blocks where 7 of them are showing while the other blocks are hiding. I have text of blocks from block 1 to block 17. When I press on the down arrow button from block 1 to block 17, the blocks will move up using 'rowheight' which it looks good to go, but there is a problem. When I press on the up arrow button and the down arrow button after the block 7, the blocks supposed to stay where they are but it will move up when the yellow block is on the block 8, block 9, block 10, block 11, block 12, block 13, block 14, block 15, block 16 and block 17.

I think the problem are somewhere in this code:

```
if (event.keyCode == 40) 
  {    //down
    if(current_col < totalrowcount && current_row == 1)
    {
      if(current_col >= displayrowcount)
      {
        var currentrowtop = $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top");
        currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)-rowheight;
        var rowtop = currentrowtop+="px";
        $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top", rowtop );
      }
      current_col++;
    }
  }
```

In this case, when I press on the down arrow button from block 1 to block 7 and if I press on the up arrow button, the blocks will not move up where it stays on. When I press on the down arrow button after the block 7, if I press on the up arrow button and then the down arrow button, the blocks will move up. The same things that goes for other blocks. I want the blocks to move up only when I'm after the end of the block where the blocks are hiding, e.g.: I'm on the block 7 while the other blocks after the block 7 are hiding so I can move them up. I don't want to move the blocks up when I'm not the end of the block.

Does anyone know how I can block the blocks from move up when I'm not after the end of the block while the other blocks are hiding?

Here's my example site if you need to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/VZWNE/6/

Comment: does anyone know how I can blocked the blocks from move up when I'm not after the end of the block while the other blocks are hiding?

Comment: Like I said in the chatroom, if you can make a fiddle, I can help. If you get stuck making a fiddle, I can help with that, too. Learning to make fiddles will be a good experience (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whitehat101/VZWNE/10/

At line 51, I added an if statement:

```
if(current_col > displayrowcount){
    $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top", "+="+rowheight);
}
```

---

I changed a few other things as well, but they weren't about your issue. Readability, and really contrived code...

Quite frankly, a lot of your code shows a lack of understanding of js fundamentals. The code is littered with `parseInt()`, and much of the time it is completely unnecessary.

For example, this made me die a little on the inside:

```
for(var i=1; i<=(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1)); i++ )
// current_row is already an int...
for(var i=1; i<=current_row+1; i++ )
```

To make things worse, one use of that hideous code was in a broken code block. All throughout your code you use `current_col` to hold the current row. And I'll guess that `current_row` actually reflects the current column.

`$(".mainWrap div.row:first-child")` occurs six times in your code.

And for this code block...

```
if(current_col > 1 && current_row == 1)
{
  var currentrowtop = $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top");   
  var calcuatedrowtop = -(current_col*rowheight);
  currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)-rowheight;

  if((currentrowtop - calcuatedrowtop) < rowheight)
  {
 currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)+rowheight;
 currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)+rowheight;
 var rowtop = currentrowtop+="px";
 $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top", rowtop );            
  }
//...
}
```

I can't even imagine a *less clear* way to write that code.

You don't the local `currentrowtop` anywhere else in it's scope. You subtract `rowheight` and then in your `if`, you add it, twice, and then use it, but if your `if` is never processed, the subtracted `currentrowtop` is never used. Lastly, `var rowtop = currentrowtop+="px";` I don't even know what to say. Do you understand what the `+=` operator does?

I would **seriously** spend time working on your JavaScript/jQuery fundamentals before embarking on a project like this.

Good luck to you.